# Problems including a service reference to a .NET web site

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcfserviceclient

I have a web service created by me, which I include in a .NET console project successfully, while it is impossible to include to a web site project.
Each time I add a web reference, my assistant does not find the service locally, but if I introduce the web URL, it is there.
Besides, automatically generated classes are totally different in the console application from those generated in web site application.

The web service is a WFC service, and it has callback functions, so I need some interface like `IServiceLectorTarjetasSharpCallback`, that I cannot find when I add the reference to my web site.

I am using VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid code generation when possible. If you want, try this:

1. Create contract assembly to define service interface and contract:

`[ServiceContract]
        public interface IService
        {
            [OperationContract]
            CustomResponse Test(string test);
        }
        public class CustomResponse { }`

2. Import contract dll and implement the service normally in service project:

`public class ServiceImplementation : IService
        {
            public CustomResponse Test(string test)
            {
                 return new CustomResponse();
            }
        }`

3. Implement Client in client assembly referencing contract as well:

`public interface IServiceClient { CustomResponse Test(string test); }
        public class ServiceClient : ClientBase< IService>, IServiceClient
        {
            public CustomResponse Test(string test)
            {
                return Channel.Test(test);
            }
        }`

4. Consume client:

`IServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(); //or some DI
        var result = client.Test("Test");`

Comment: Ok !!Thanks for your advice. I will try it and afterward tell you the outcomes. Thanks again.